# Stream H.264 video over rtp using gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, gstreamer, rtp

I am newbie with gstreamer and I am trying to be used with it. My first target is to create a simple rtp stream of h264 video between two devices. I am using these two pipelines:

Sender: `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=c:\\tmp\\sample_h264.mov ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

Receiver:
`gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! decodebin ! autovideosink`

But with the first one (the sender) I got the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PE*R*O L(LgIsNtG- l.a.u.n
h-1.0:5788): CRITICAL **: gst_adapter_map: assertion `size > 0' failed
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2812): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I tried a lot of other configurations but I couldn’t find the right pipeline.

Some other information:
  Gstreamer version: 1.0.7
  OS: Windows 7

Any idea/suggestion?
Thx,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`filesrc` will read the data from the given file as raw bytes; you cannot just encode these raw bytes with `x264enc`, you will need video-data for this to work. try adding a *demuxer*/*decoder* before re-encoding the stream), e.g. something like this:

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
   filesrc location=/tmp/sample_h264.mov
   ! qtdemux \
   ! h264parse \
   ! ffdec_h264 \
   ! ffmpegcolorspace \
   ! x264enc \
   ! rtph264pay \
   ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

You should do a quick check whether this works by using a test video soure:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
   videotestsrc 
   ! x264enc \
   ! rtph264pay \
   ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint raw/video data but I think this solves just one par of the problem. I tried the classic pipeline with videotestsrc but nothing is going to the other side. Even with the following pipeline I cannot receive anything on the other side:
`gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! udpsink host=192.128.52.128 port=9001`
I have the feeling that the udpsink is not sending anything!
PS: is not a problem of firewall, I deactivate all of them

Comment: Trying with:
`ffmpeg -i C:\tmp\sample_h264.mov -f mpegts udp://192.168.52.128:9001`
… and the stream is received in the other side. But I want to do it with gstreamer

Comment: `videotestsrc ! udpsink` is *not* an RTP stream. you have to add a payloader

Comment: `gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! udpsink host=192.128.52.128 port=9001`output:
`Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock`

Comment: Even with rtph264pay I had the same result

Comment: Finally, I think that the problem was related to Windows. The two following pipelines work fine between two different Ubuntu VMs but not on Windows:

Sender: `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/ … /sample_h264.mov ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.52.129 port=9001`

Receiver: `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=9001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`