# gst-launch bogus 'no element "udpsrc"' error

Tags: udp, gstreamer

The command: *gst-launch udpsrc port=5000*
returns: *ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "udpsrc"*.

The command: *gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://239.194.0.177:1026* does not, and executes (presumably) correctly.

The first command is from many streaming tutorials, e.g. [this one](http://www.wumpus-cave.net/2015/11/06/low-latency-fpv-streaming-with-the-raspberry-pi/).
The second command was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39538695). it's just to show that udpsrc is present.
They were cut down to just the offending part.

I have everything gstreamer1.0 - related up-to-date (for Ubuntu 16.04.6):

```
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 is already the newest version (3.0.18-1).
gstreamer1.0-clutter is already the newest version (2.0.18-1).
gstreamer1.0-crystalhd is already the newest version (1:0.0~git20110715.fdd2f19-11build1).
gstreamer1.0-dvswitch is already the newest version (0.1.1-1).
gstreamer1.0-espeak is already the newest version (0.4.0-1).
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 is already the newest version (0.10.32.debian-1).
gstreamer1.0-nice is already the newest version (0.1.13-0ubuntu2).
gstreamer1.0-pocketsphinx is already the newest version (0.8.0+real5prealpha-1ubuntu2).
gstreamer1.0-alsa is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3).
gstreamer1.0-doc is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-dbg is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-doc is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4).
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.4).
gstreamer1.0-tools is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-x is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3).
libgstreamer1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
libgstreamer1.0-0-dbg is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
libgstreamer1.0-dev is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-libav is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-libav-dbg is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-packagekit is already the newest version (0.8.17-4ubuntu6~gcc5.4ubuntu1.4).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-doc is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-dbg is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-doc is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-vaapi is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-vaapi-doc is already the newest version (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1).
gstreamer1.0-hybris:i386 is already the newest version (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2).



$ gst-inspect-1.0 udpsrc
Factory Details:
  Rank                     none (0)
  Long-name                UDP packet receiver
  Klass                    Source/Network
  Description              Receive data over the network via UDP
  Author                   Wim Taymans <wim@fluendo.com>, Thijs Vermeir <thijs.vermeir@barco.com>

Plugin Details:
  Name                     udp
  Description              transfer data via UDP
  Filename                 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstudp.so
  Version                  1.8.3
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-good
  Source release date      2016-08-19
  Binary package           GStreamer Good Plugins (Ubuntu)
  Origin URL               https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good1.0

GObject
 +----GInitiallyUnowned
       +----GstObject
             +----GstElement
                   +----GstBaseSrc
                         +----GstPushSrc
                               +----GstUDPSrc

Implemented Interfaces:
  GstURIHandler

Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      ANY


Element Flags:
  no flags set

Element Implementation:
  Has change_state() function: 0x7f38aa386e10

Element has no clocking capabilities.

URI handling capabilities:
  Element can act as source.
  Supported URI protocols:
    udp

Pads:
  SRC: 'src'
    Pad Template: 'src'

Element Properties:
  name                : The name of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "udpsrc0"
  parent              : The parent of the object
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Object of type "GstObject"
  blocksize           : Size in bytes to read per buffer (-1 = default)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer. Range: 0 - 4294967295 Default: 4096 
  num-buffers         : Number of buffers to output before sending EOS (-1 = unlimited)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: -1 - 2147483647 Default: -1 
  typefind            : Run typefind before negotiating
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: false
  do-timestamp        : Apply current stream time to buffers
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  port                : The port to receive the packets from, 0=allocate
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 65535 Default: 5004 
  multicast-group     : The Address of multicast group to join. (DEPRECATED: Use address property instead)
                        flags: readable, writable, deprecated
                        String. Default: "0.0.0.0"
  multicast-iface     : The network interface on which to join the multicast group
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  uri                 : URI in the form of udp://multicast_group:port
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "udp://0.0.0.0:5004"
  caps                : The caps of the source pad
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Caps (NULL)
  socket              : Socket to use for UDP reception. (NULL == allocate)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Object of type "GSocket"
  buffer-size         : Size of the kernel receive buffer in bytes, 0=default
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 2147483647 Default: 0 
  timeout             : Post a message after timeout nanoseconds (0 = disabled)
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Unsigned Integer64. Range: 0 - 18446744073709551615 Default: 0 
  skip-first-bytes    : number of bytes to skip for each udp packet
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Integer. Range: 0 - 2147483647 Default: 0 
  close-socket        : Close socket if passed as property on state change
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  used-socket         : Socket currently in use for UDP reception. (NULL = no socket)
                        flags: readable
                        Object of type "GSocket"
  auto-multicast      : Automatically join/leave multicast groups
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  reuse               : Enable reuse of the port
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
  address             : Address to receive packets for. This is equivalent to the multicast-group property for now
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: "0.0.0.0"
  loop                : Used for setting the multicast loop parameter. TRUE = enable, FALSE = disable
                        flags: readable, writable
                        Boolean. Default: true
```

What the hell?
Or, if it's "unclear what I'm asking": what do I need to do / reorder / adjust / reconfigure / recompile / etc to receive a stream coming in at port 5000? Most examples I've seen start with "gst-launch udpsrc port=...".

Comment: `udpsrc` element is from `gst-plugins-good`, so first check if you have it installed. Second, try run `gst-inspect-1.0 udpsrc` to check if it installed correctly.

Comment: @RSATom `gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version`, it's there. And I've added the output of `gst-inspect-1.0 udpsrc` - it finds 1.8.3 that supports the 'port' property. But really, the presence of udpsrc has never been in question - recall that the second command works.

Comment: I have one more idea: in first command you use `gst-launch` but in second `gst-launch-1.0` - maybe it's the reason of your problem. You should always use `gst-launch-1.0`

Comment: It looks like `gst-launch` is related to GStreamer 0.1, and you don't have `udpsrc` installed for GStramer 0.1

Comment: @RSATom Wow thanks, I somehow missed that. Even after comparing side-by-side. Well, works now. What should I do with this question? If you turn that observation into an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first command you use `gst-launch` but in second `gst-launch-1.0` - it's the reason of your problem. You should always use `gst-launch-1.0`. `gst-launch` is related to GStreamer 0.1

Answer (score 1):

I had this error today as well, but for a different reason. I'm posting this answer just in case anyone else happens to come across it as well.

It turns out I did not have all the development packages for GStreamer installed, specifically **[gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.16.0.msi](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/#windows)** (it should be noted this is on my Windows machine). After I installed that, GStreamer was able to locate udpsrc.